# Ionic: How Can i show default image in case of image source error?

Tags: image-processing, ionic4

I have a case that, **I want to show default image in case of image source error.**

My souce code is here,

```
<ion-img [src]="assets/imgs/avatar7.png" (ionError)="this.src=assets/imgs/avatar7.png" ></ion-img>
```

this throwing error as

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'png' of undefined
```

[image]

Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: Two years late but you were missing the quotes (ionError)="this.src='assets/imgs/avatar7.png' "

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it wont happen that way,

I would suggest you doing it this way:

add and ngIf directive for your ion-img

```
<div *ngIf="!assets/imgs/avatar7.png">
<ion-img [src]="path to error image"  ></ion-img>
</div> 

<div *ngIf="assets/imgs/avatar7.png">
<ion-img [src]="path to image"  ></ion-img>
</div>
```

You evaluate either if the image path exist or not. And show the respective image you want.